Calculating route using Itinero don't work
I tried to write simple code to calculate route for cars. I use Itinero library for .NET. And even if I have the same code as many other people in tutorials, I still get an error when running the code, that the points I try to calculate route for are out of the network. Event if though I even used point obtained from the osm file. I don't know, what I am doing wrong.
Currently, I have simple code, which should do this:

Load the RouterDB file with data for Czech Republic are, which is the target of my app (I convert the file from pbf to routerdb using IDP) and deserialize it
calculate the route from coordinates, which I get from Google Maps from randomly selected points on road, using this code

using Itinero.LocalGeo;
using Itinero;

RouterDb routerDb = new RouterDb();

string path = @"path"; //I have real path in my code
using (var stream = new FileInfo(path).OpenRead())
{
    routerDb = RouterDb.Deserialize(stream);
}
var router = new Router(routerDb);

var profile = router.Db.GetSupportedProfile("car");

Coordinate from = new Coordinate(49.777423f, 13.355180f);
Coordinate to = new Coordinate(49.777729f, 13.358398f);

List<RouterPoint> points = new List<RouterPoint>
{
    router.TryResolve(profile, from, 200).Value,
    router.TryResolve(profile, to, 200).Value
};

var route = router.TryCalculate(profile, points.ToArray());

float drivingTime = route.Value.TotalTime;

I think this should work, but it doesn't. I tried a lot of other variants of code, but none of them worked. I hope someone helps me to find answer.
